# How can I do a [MemberNotNull] for an Entity Framework IncludeAll() method I wrote?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following helper method. This includes all complex properties in my Event DbSet (actually there's 9 properties but I reduced it for clarity):

```
public static IQueryable<Event> IncludeAll(this IQueryable<Event> source)
{
    return source
        .Include(e => e.Description)
        .Include(e => e.Tags)
        .Include(e => e.Thumbnail);
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
_event = await dbContext.Events
    .IncludeAll()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == pkEvent);
```

When I do this, I get warnings in that call that it may need Description, Tags, & Thumbnail. And in the first use of each, again warnings that they may be null.

Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
[MemberNotNull(nameof(Description))]
public static IQueryable<Event> IncludeAll(this IQueryable<Event> source)
```

That specifically does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For me I define those navigation properties as not nallable and assign `null!` value to them.

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id {get; init;}
    public Description Description {get; set;} = null!;
}
```

I know it's not recommended to use `null!` assignment, but I found it a good solusion that I know I would include it when it's required in my code.

To make some more restriction about this I access my Data using the [specification pattern](https://github.com/ardalis/Specification) so it would be just one plase to incluse the naviation properties

Comment: I don't like that approach because it then loses a lot of the help nullability provides.

Comment: I can argue a bit about that. The nullability of your Navigation Properties pertains more to business requirements than to technical challenges. What I mean is that based on your business rules, you determine whether every Event should have a Description object or if it's optional. You should then model your domain accordingly.
When you retrieve your Domain Objects from the data store, you should meet the requirements within the context of that specific operation. You shouldn't mark your navigation properties as nullable if they aren't nullable in practical scenarios.

Comment: They are very nullable in practible scenarios as in most cases I pull down just the select few I need. So that does tell me, outside of the IncludeAll() scenario, if I've done an Include() on properties I'm then accessing.